# MYSQL QUERY:How to get the origin_url and word where the count of same origin_url great 2?

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: table]

How to get the origin_url and word where the count of same origin_url great 2?
I want get this result:

```
>1.com home
>1.com word
>2.com def
>2.com eee
>3.com asd
>3.com fda
```

Comment: count of `3.com` is not greater than 2, it's exactly 2.

Comment: Why doesn't the desired output have `1.com pet`, `1.com ddd`, `2.com adf`?

Answer (score 1):

Join the table with a subquery that counts the repetitions of `origin_url` and only returns the ones with counter greater than 2.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable AS t1
JOIN (SELECT origin_url
      FROM yourTable
      GROUP BY origin_url
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 2) AS t2
ON t1.origin_url = t2.origin_url
```